# How to block the onTap over a specific widget in the subtree?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this widget:

```dart
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    print('Tapped');
  },
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
    children: [
      Text('Text'),
      TextButton( // <- I tried to wrap it with AbsorbPointer.
        child: Text('Disable'),
        onPressed: null,
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

[image]

It is an `InkWell` with an `onTap` (in this example, it only prints `'Tapped'`), and inside there is a button that can be (not all the time) disabled.

My issue is that when the `TextButton` is disabled, clicking on it triggers the `onTap` of the `InkWell`. I would like to block this and if the user clicks on the disable button, nothing happens.

I tried to wrap the `TextButton` with an `AbsorbPointer` but it didn't work.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can sync the state of `InkWell` and `TextButton`.

```
// Wrapping this inside a Stateful Widget
bool isEnable = false; // This is state of InkWell and TextButton

// Your widget
InkWell(
  onTap: isEnable
    ? () {
      print('Tapped');
    }
    : null,
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
    children: [
      Text('Text'),
      TextButton(
        child: Text('Disable'),
        onPressed: isEnable
          ? () {
            // Your actions
          }
          : null,
      ),
    ],
  ),
),

// and you can change both widgets state by using `setState`
setState(() {
  isEnable = !isEnable;
});
```

It will be better if you move your actions out of widget codes

```
// Wrapping this inside a Stateful Widget
bool isEnable = false; // This is state of InkWell and TextButton

void _inkWellActions() {}

void _textButtonActions() {}

// Your widget
InkWell(
  onTap: isEnable
    ? _inkWellActions
    : null,
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
    children: [
      Text('Text'),
      TextButton(
        child: Text('Disable'),
        onPressed: isEnable
          ? _textButtonActions
          : null,
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: I don't want to disable the InkWell. I still want it to be enabled. For example, I want the print to happen when I click on `Text`. What I want to do is to block/absorb the pointer when the user clicks on the disabled button so the `InkWell.onTap` is not triggerred (like when the button is enabled)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Container(
  color: Colors.grey[300],
  child: Row(
    children:  [
      Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: InkWell(
            onTap: (){
              print('Tapped');
            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: const [
                  Text('Text'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ),

      const TextButton(
        onPressed: null,
        child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text('Disable'),
            ),
       ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

output

[image]

I hope is this helpful

Comment: What you did was to move the Button outside the `InkWell`. I cannot do that, my example was a simplified one, and I maybe you can consider `Row(children: [Text('Text'), TextButton(...), Text('Other text on the right')])` to be the children of my `InkWell`. Plus, I want to preserve the hover and splash effects to be all over the area (including the button) when I click on the `InkWell`

Comment: Do you want this ? when the TextButton is disabled & user clicking on TextButton at that time  triggers the onTap of the InkWell .  But You would like to block this click event when user click on TextButton right?